# Error in b[1]/b[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to calculate x-intercept for the model. The model runs fine but I'm getting an error `Error in b[1]/b[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator` when calculating `x-intercept`.

Here is my code for the model & its summary

```
mod <-
  glmmTMB(total_count ~  mean_temp + (1|month), family = nbinom1, data = df)

summary(mod)

Family: nbinom1  ( log )
Formula:          total_count ~ mean_temp + (1 | month)
Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   251.2    258.9   -121.6    243.2       46 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 month  (Intercept) 3.415    1.848   
Number of obs: 50, groups:  month, 10

Dispersion parameter for nbinom1 family (): 43.8 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.58553    2.01287   0.291    0.771
mean_temp    0.06466    0.12167   0.531    0.595
```

Here is the code for calculating `x-intercept`. I need to add `C` because it's a negative binomial model

```
C <- 0.01

b <- fixef(mod)


x_intercept <- log(C) - b[1]/b[2]
```

Error in b[1]/b[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

When I try to covert `b` to `numeric`, I get an error `Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Reproducible example

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    month = structure(
      c(
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L
      ),
      .Label = c(
        "April",
        "August",
        "December",
        "July",
        "June",
        "March",
        "May",
        "November",
        "October",
        "September"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    total_count = c(
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      29L,
      44L,
      10L,
      5L,
      2L,
      2L,
      43L,
      1L,
      0L,
      4L,
      10L,
      2L,
      4L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      3L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      1L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      0L,
      41L,
      7L,
      47L,
      1L,
      131L,
      81L,
      82L,
      409L,
      204L
    ),
    mean_temp = c(
      11.35,
      11.35,
      11.35,
      11.35,
      11.35,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      4.66,
      4.66,
      4.66,
      4.66,
      4.66,
      20.49,
      20.49,
      20.49,
      20.49,
      20.49,
      20.78,
      20.78,
      20.78,
      20.78,
      20.78,
      10.31,
      10.31,
      10.31,
      10.31,
      10.31,
      20.59,
      20.59,
      20.59,
      16.3,
      16.3,
      11.66,
      11.66,
      11.66,
      11.66,
      11.66,
      14.14,
      14.14,
      14.14,
      14.14,
      14.14,
      17.95,
      17.95,
      17.95,
      17.95,
      17.95
    )
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-50L)
)
```

Comment: what values do you want to divide? ie what do you think `b[1]` is referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
b
Conditional model:
(Intercept)    mean_temp  
    0.58553      0.06466
```

displaye as above is not numeric. is of class:

```
class(b)
[1] "fixef.glmmTMB"
```

You could see all the values in `b` by using `unclass`:

```
unclass(b)
$cond
(Intercept)   mean_temp 
 0.58552627  0.06466185 

$zi
numeric(0)

$disp
(Intercept) 
   3.780722
```

Now i believe when you write `b[1]` you mean to use the `b$cond[1]`

Thus you could compute your quantity using :

```
C <- 0.01

log(C) - b[[1]][1]/b[[1]][2]
(Intercept) 
  -13.66038
```

Comment: This is fine, but I would say that ```b <- as.list(fixef(mod)$cond); with(b, log(C) - `(Intercept)`/mean_temp)``` (or ```b <- fixef(mod)$cond; log(C) - b$`(Intercept)`/b$mean_temp``` if you don't like `with()` magic) would be better practice (i.e., avoid using numeric indices when the structures you're working with have meaningful names that you could use instead)

Comment: Thank you both! I got an output, but the value is `-13.66038 `. I'm not sure if this has any practical meaning because anything below zero is freezing, and it will be impossible to get disease below freezing point anyway. I don't need a model to tell me that plant disease cannot occur at `-13 degree Celsius`. If the value was positive, then it might have been useful. Thanks again

Comment: @Ahsk first note that `log(0.01)` is already `-4.60517`. I am not sure  what you are looking for although `b` already has a `disp` intercept

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code here as per se. I am following this `x-intercept` method http://uspest.org/wea/Boxwood_blight_risk_model_summaryV21.pdf to calculate `temperature threshold - temperature at which there will be zero disease`. I am just saying this might not be the right method for finding thresholds.